# Why is it not "paddleboarding positions"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

According to Merriam Webster, **paddleboard** refers to the board itself. The activity, as Wikipedia suggests, is paddlebarding. Why do these sentences use **paddleboard safety, paddleboard positions**, instead of **paddleboarding safety, paddleboarding positions**?

> The commission has been looking at **paddleboard safety** since early last year, focusing on rental companies, the panel's chairman, Bill Kenney, said. ([LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/local/lanow/la-me-ln-paddleboard-leashes-20180513-story.html))
>
> As part of the lesson, Berlett guided me through useful **paddleboard positions**. ([Journal Sentinel](https://www.jsonline.com/story/entertainment/festivals/summerfest/2018/06/30/how-go-paddleboarding-summerfest-and-not-completely-wipe-out/745497002/))
>
> The weekend includes nine running, standup **paddleboard**, and triathlon races that draw everyone from kids as young as 8 to triathlon’s top pros. ([Sunset](https://www.sunset.com/travel/hotels/all-inclusive-resorts))

Comment: I think "paddleboard safety" focuses on the board itself, for example adding a leash to the board to increase its safety. It's not the safety concerns while you are doing the paddleboarding. Just my opinion. I might be wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Paddleboard safety** refers to safe practices when using paddleboards. These practices may include actions that are taken before or after the actual act of paddleboarding. Consider the analogous situation with **firearms** (the equipment) and **shooting** (the activity). **Firearm safety** includes precautions that must be taken before and after the actual activity of shooting, including prep, storage, etc.

In general, terms like these are relevant to the equipment overall rather than being exclusively relevant to the activity involving the equipment.